# Snowflake pandas Connector Kills Kernel

Tags: pandas, jupyter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble with the pandas connector for Snowflake.

The last line of this code causes the immediate death of the python kernel.  Any suggestions on how to diagnose such a situation?

```
import pyarrow
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=********,
    password=********,
    account=********,
    warehouse='compute_wh',
    database='SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA',
    schema='WEATHER'
)
cs = ctx.cursor()
cs.execute('select * from weather_14_total limit 10')
cs.fetch_pandas_all()
```

Note that if `fetch_pandas_all()` is replaced with `fetchone()` everything works fine.

Thanks in advance.

- Keith

Comment: Any errors that you can share?

Comment: All I get is a dialog panel that opens saying "Kernel Restarting.  The kernel appears to have died.  It will restart automatically."

Comment: Could it be that its because you're not actually creating a dataframe with that statement?  Last line should be: `df = cs.fetch_pandas_all()` where df becomes the name of your dataframe.  I wouldn't expect that to kill a kernel, but worth a shot, right?

Comment: Unfortunately it still kills the kernel just the same.

Comment: You should report the issue to Snowflake support.  I believe this is fairly new functionality for the Snowflake connector, so they will likely want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd 
from snowflake.connector import connect 

qry = "SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 5"

con = connect(
  account = 'ACCOUNT',
  user = 'USER',
  password = 'PASSWORD',
  role= 'ROLE',
  warehouse = 'WAREHOUSE',
  database = 'DATABASE',
  schema = 'SCHEMA'
)

df = pd.read_sql(qry, con)
```

However, this was the most upvoted answer for a similar question:

```
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

url = URL(
  account = 'xxxx',
  user = 'xxxx',
  password = 'xxxx',
  database = 'xxx',
  schema = 'xxxx',
  warehouse = 'xxx',
  role='xxxxx',
  authenticator='https://xxxxx.okta.com',
)
engine = create_engine(URL)
connection = engine.connect()

query = '''
  select * from MYDB.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
  LIMIT 10;
'''

df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Our team had this same issue last week.  The workaround for us ended up being to use the read_sql command instead.

Answer (score 0):

That pyarrow warning it throws is not to be ignored. Current databricks LTS `9.1` has incompatible pacakge versions and so `connector.fetch_pandas_all()` crashes python REPL.

### Solution:

Go to cluster -> Libraries -> Install New -> PyPI -> `pyarrow==5.0.0` -> restart